# How to set array data posted as dropdown list in key value format

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to set following array in key-value format for perticular selected dropdown  value. For ex. i have array in following format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => --Select--
            [value] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 269
            [text] => Being amount paid to supplier
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 268
            [text] => Cash Received 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [value] => 267
            [text] => Cheque Received 
        )

)
```

Now, i want to set dropdown key-value pair as given below if i found value 268 is selected

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DefaultNarration_071] => 268
        )

)
```

Can anybody please suggest me appropriate solution for above question ??

Comment: What have you created on your own? Show us your code? And your data should be in PHP format

Comment: Hello sir , I create one dropdown field in that dropdown i bind data from stored Procedure then i get result in first array which i show .after i want to set particular index value that i get into 2nd array . So how i set particular dropdown values giving index or value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array_list=array(array("value"=>0,"text"=>"--Select--"),array("value"=>268,"text"=>"Cash received"));

$selected=268;
$text="";
foreach($array_list as $entry){
    if($entry['value']==$selected){
        $text=$entry['text'];
        break;
    }
}

echo "Selected Option: ".$text;
```

Text will now contain the selected option, if I understood your question correct.

Comment: I want to set only "Cash Received" on page load. so how to set??

Comment: ...I think that is what is now in the variable $text. Your explanation is a bit weak.

Comment: How to set particular default value from array in php?

Comment: You can replace the '$text="";' with your default value, it can be written as string or also if it is the first child of the array_list: $text=array_list[0]['text'];